# NodeJS fs.unlink() deletes the files but the OS can still find them

Tags: node.js, rhel

I am using the following node.js code to delete files that I don't need.

```
fs.unlink(downloadsFolder + '/' + file, function(err){
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log("This file will be deleted." + file)
  });
```

When I list my directory, I can verify that the files are gone. However, when I run this command, I can still see them marked as `(deleted)` and still taking up disk space.

```
dzdo lsof -L | grep -i deleted

node  48782  root 600743243   403197165 /mnt/downloads/file_1516312894734.csv (deleted)
node  48782  root 14999       403197166 /mnt/downloads/file_1516729327306.csv (deleted)
```

As a temporary thing, I restart the node server to release all those "file handles" and they are gone.

Why doesn't `fs.unlink()` do this automatically?